# how to use jQuery in Code Igniter 2.x.x?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

In my config file I have `$config['jquery'] = 'js/jquery.js';`

My `jquery.js` file resides outside of the application folder, and is inside the js folder

In my controller I have

```
public $jquery

public function __construct(){
  $this->jquery = $this->config->item('jquery');
}

public function index(){
  $data['jquery'] = $this->jquery;
  $this->load->view('site_view',$data);
}
```

In my view file I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo "$base/$jquery" ;?>'></script>
```

Now the question is,
When I do some basic jQuery scripts why does it not work?
I tried adding an external `js.js` file which contains a very basic jquery script for checking a box and disabling a button.

It doesn't work unless I use vanilla javascript in the view file itself.

I don't know what's going on, I even included the js folder at the htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
```

Anyone knows what is happening?
In other frameworks I never had problems including jquery at all.

Comment: Hard to answer without more to go on.  view source and tell us the exact path that is being output.

Comment: could u check with firebug if jquery andthis externajs.js file are actually present inside html.

Comment: this is how it looked at the view source <script type="text/javascript" src='http ://ci/paragon/js/jquery.js'></script> (ignore the space after http )

Answer (score 0):

Look at your source,

You are using an absolute path instead of a valid `http://` path  try using [site_url](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) like so

`<?php echo site_url($jquery);?>`

Note that this assumes your setup looks something like

> /
>   /Application
>   /System
>   /Css
>   /js
>   /index.php
>   /.htaccess